# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers (WIFI not recognized on Ubuntu 17.10 on Macbook Pro)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I managed to get online through a Ethernet to USB adapter, but I still need help in having the WiFi in my new Ubuntu 17.10  installation finally work.

I tried downloading the driver (with the other 3 AMD64 dependencies),as described in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-driver) but I get the following error.

Ubuntu is running on a SDHC Card on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7.

Please help!

[The terminal error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQreO.jpg)

[The procedure I followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XXR.png)

Comment: You're missing all the other build dependencies for GCC, etc. that `dkms` needs.  That's a *very* complex web of packages you'll need to download and install, and might not be the easiest thing in the world to do...

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas for your reply. How is it possible that I'm missing all these packages? I installed the normal Ubuntu 17.10 image file following all the directions on the Ubuntu website.

Comment: the Ubuntu images do *not* contain the compiler and software-building-dependencies (aka `build-essential` in an `apt-get install` command, which in turn relies on the entire tree of compiler dependency packages) by default.  That's why you're missing the dependencies of `dkms`, including but not limited to `gcc`, `make`, etc. which you need to compile with.  I hate to ask but is there any reason you can't, say, connect to an Ethernet port for a short while on this machine to install the drivers and stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately, my macbook has no ethernet port. Unless there's a way to connect ethernet through the USB or thunderbold ports, I'm out of luck. Would getting a USB Wifi stick to download them work or would I need another driver for that?

Comment: You would probably need a driver for that.  You might be able to get one of those USB Ethernet adapters and use that, but I'm not fluent in Mac hardware enough to say what would or wouldn't work.  (I got a cheap one off of NewEgg a while back for my laptop, it's worked in *all* my systems so far)

Comment: Well, I guess it would come down again on wether Ubuntu has the driver for the USB Ethernet Adapter installed or not...am I wrong?

Comment: Hi again Thomas, the USB Ethernet Adapter fortunately didn't require any additional driver. So I'm online now but could you please tell me specifically how to proceed to download and install the "very complex web of packages" I need to have the WiFi work?